FastAPI WebSocket behavior differs unexpectedly
I'm trying to get updates from mySql table and send them over socket
I'm working with FastAPI WebSockets and experiencing different behaviors based on the loop condition. Here's my code:
@app.websocket("/msg3")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        message = f"Server message at {datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')} here"
        await websocket.send_text(message)

        await websocket.send_text("1")
        await websocket.send_text("2")
        
        stream = BinLogStreamReader(
                connection_settings=MYSQL_SETTINGS,
                server_id=100,
                blocking=True,
                resume_stream=True,
                only_events=[UpdateRowsEvent],
                only_tables=["live_status"],
                only_schemas=["parking"]
            )

        await websocket.send_text("Started monitoring MySQL binary logs...")
        await websocket.send_text("3")
        

        # HERE PROBLEM OCCURS
        while True:
                for binlogevent in stream:
                    await websocket.send_text("stream-data")
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
        else:
            await websocket.send_text("4")
            await websocket.send_text("5")
            await websocket.send_text("6")
            await websocket.send_text("7")
            await websocket.send_text("8")
            
        
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


Current Behavior:
With while False:
I receive messages in this order:
11:38 53.80 - 8
11:38 53.78 - 7
11:38 53.76 - 6
11:38 53.74 - 5
11:38 53.73 - 4
11:38 53.71 - 3
11:38 53.68 - Started monitoring MySQL binary logs...
11:38 53.67 - 2
11:38 53.65 - 1
11:38 53.64 - Server message at 11:38:53 here

With while True:
I only receive the first message:
11:39 05.76 - Server message at 11:39:05 here
11:39 05.74 - Connected to ws://127.0.0.1:9999/msg3
Then it stops sending messages

When I'm saying While True/False I'm thinking of second while
# HERE PROBLEM OCCURS
        while True:
                for binlogevent in stream:
                    await websocket.send_text("stream-data")
                await asyncio.sleep(1)

Questions:
Why does changing the loop condition from False to True cause such different behavior?
What's happening with the execution flow in both cases?
How can I properly structure this code to handle both MySQL binary log monitoring and sequential message sending?
Environment:
Any insights into this behavior and suggestions for proper implementation would be greatly appreciated.
